# MySQL: find all records with empty anchor tags in a field (regex) and remove them

Tags: mysql, html, regex

I have a table which has a column containing html code. I need to find out all records that have empty anchor tags in them, ignoring child tags. Afterwards I want to remove all those empty tags.

To clarify things - these anchors should be found, for example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank"></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"> </a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><span><strong></strong></span></a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><span></span></a>
```

Whereas these should not be found:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">something</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><span>some text</span></a>
```

I managed to get all empty anchors (like in the first example) with this query:

```
select * from table_a where html regexp '<a.*href=".*".*></a>'
```

But this does not find the 2nd and 3rd example. Can someone help?

UPDATE:
I want to remove those empty tags from the database. I fiddled around with MySQLs UpdateXML but have not found a solution yet.

Comment: The second example can be found by extending your regex to look for zero or more whitespace characters between the `>` and `</`. The third would take a bit more work, and my regex skills are (unfortunately) quite lacking so I can't help with that.

Comment: That's a pity ;-) Thanks anyway for the hint on the 2nd example.

Comment: Regexes + HTML = severe pain. I'd suggest doing this purely client-side with a DOM parser, as anything with regex WILL blow up on you at some point.

Comment: I already thought about writing a little PHP script for that. Performance is no problem here as this is a once-only-query I need to find out some broken records.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use [xml functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html) in order to extract needed text nodes from xml document.

```
update table_a 
set html = UpdateXML(html, '//a', '')
where ExtractValue(html, '//a//text()') regexp '^[[:space:]]*$'
```

*Note: if the table has a field with several `a` tags where some of them are empty and others are non-empty then this field will not be updated.*

Comment: I hadn't the time to try it so far (some other more important stuff came up), but I have it in mind and try it out as soon as I can - and accept the answer if it works ;-) Looks like a good approach so far!

Comment: I now had some time to try this (finally). Your example returns all rows in the table, even those containing no anchor tags in the html column - probably because ExtractValue returns always an empty string even if the selector doesn't find anything.

Comment: @acme For me it works fine. ExtractValue returns NULL if selector doesn't find anything. Can you give sample html which does not work as expected?

Comment: I tried `select ExtractValue('<p>this is a test</p>', '//a//text()') regexp '^[[:space:]]*$'` which returns 1, though there is no anchor in it. According to the MySQL docs the function only returns NULL when there is an error with the xml. It also says "No distinction is made between a match on an empty element and no match at all." (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)

Comment: @acme Oh, my mistake. But perhaps this should not be the problem, because your purpose is to update the table. When you update the field (using UpdateXML) which has no `a` tags in it, then the field value is left untouched. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it seems the most closest way - the only problem I still have are the rows that have multiple `<a>`'s in this field. So the UpdateXML seems to be a dead-end in this case when it leaves out rows with more anchors where some needs to be replaced :-(

Answer (score 0):

an extra .* at the end:

```
<a.*href=".*".*>.*</a>
```

Comment: This returns all records with anchors. But I need to find only the ones with no visible text in it. Added some "not-to-find" examples in the post.